# jQuery .addClass() and .removeClass() only applies to first instance of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    var $info = $('#thumb');

    enquire.register("(max-width: 480px)", {

    match: function() {      
    $info.removeClass('col-xs-6');
    $info.addClass('col-xs-12');
    },


    unmatch: function() {
    $info.removeClass('col-xs-12');
    $info.addClass('col-xs-6');      
    }

    }).listen();

    </script>
```

I am using `Enquire.js` to dynamically add and remove css classes from elements.

**The above code works but only for the first `'#thumb'`. I have about 12 elements which have the `thumb` id. Anyone know how I can apply it to all elements with the same ID**

Comment: __IDs in HTML must be unique.__ You can use a common class and the use class selector. As an alternative you can use `var $info = $("[id=thumb])"` but not recommended.

Comment: id must be unique, instead of that add class thumb and apply on class

Comment: Also the selector is run on script load so will not include dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a class. ID's are unique so they can only apply it once. If you do:    $('.thumb')    then you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you to run your source through an [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/), which would help point out that it's not valid to have more than one element with the same id. Which is why it's only updating the first of your 12 elements.

Take a read through this http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ is one quick reference that can hopefully explain the what/why/how of what's going on here.

Comment: Useful but this should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Is it more appropriate as an answer if an updated code snip is provided?

Comment: Sure although you pointed out that IDs should be unique (as did others in pure comments) a revised snippet always adds value and makes your answer more valuable to future visitors.

Answer (score -1):

#xxx is get by id. and you need to make sure this id is unique. If you want to get by class is .xxx for get by class, you will get it in array. So need to to use for-loop to addclass or removeclass